# Help identifying this shrub

Tags: shrubs

Does anyone know the name of the two shrubs in this picture?

[image]

Comment: Welcome! Please see [the info on identification questions](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/tags/identification/info). We need more details than a blurry overview photo. And also note that we can accept only one identification question per post, so if you want two plants identified, please post two different questions. The [tour] and the [help], especially [ask], will explain more about how the site works.

Comment: Do those shrubs have leaves that come in pink, the change to a spotted pale yellow/green? Look like a Nishiki Willow to me. Silly me... I should have zoomed in first... I think you need to take a few more photos.

Comment: There are two shrubs, but they are the same so just one plant is being identified. I will try and get a better picture. The house is on a real estate site so the photos are not all that great. I'll try to get some in person. This yard has a tree canopy and shade/filtered light very similar to mine and these appear to be doing very well (other factors such as soil, watering are unknown). Here are a few more pictures to give yard context, but they might not be helpful as they aren't close up.

Comment: For previous comment: [Photo](https://bit.ly/2ZrPRB7) Location is Los Angeles, a few miles from the coast.